# Xcode 7.3 + linking to relative paths = ld: file not found: ../lib/lib_.dylib

Tags: xcode, linker, xcode7, dynamic-linking, xcode7.3

I have a project which compiles fine on Xcode 7.2 and earlier, but [gets linker errors when compiling with Xcode 7.3](https://github.com/leedm777/homebrew-asterisk/issues/22). I've been able to narrow it down to a [simple example project](https://github.com/leedm777/bug-free-eureka) that duplicates the problem.

The basic project structure is like this:

```
.
├── one
│   ├── lib
│   │   └── lib1.dylib
│   └── src
│       └── one.c
├── two
│   ├── lib
│   │   └── lib2.dylib
│   └── src
│       └── three.c
└── three
    ├── lib
    │   └── lib3.dylib
    └── src
        └── two.c
```

`lib3` links with `lib2`, and `lib2` links with `lib1`. When the library is compiled, its output is in the `../lib` directory relative to its `src` directory.

When I try to compile `lib3`, it errors with `file not found: ../lib/lib1.dylib`, even though `../../one/lib` is in the library search path.

What strange and mystical linker flag can I use to get the search paths to work out okay? Or is this a bug with Xcode?

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -C one/src
cc -I ../../include   -c -o one.o one.c
cc -dynamiclib -undefined dynamic_lookup -flat_namespace -o ../lib/lib1.dylib one.o
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -C two/src
cc -I ../../include   -c -o two.o two.c
cc -dynamiclib -undefined dynamic_lookup -flat_namespace -L ../../one/lib -o ../lib/lib2.dylib two.o -l1
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -C three/src
cc -I ../../include   -c -o three.o three.c
cc -dynamiclib -undefined dynamic_lookup -flat_namespace -L ../../two/lib -L ../../one/lib -o ../lib/lib3.dylib three.o -l2
ld: file not found: ../lib/lib1.dylib for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[1]: *** [../lib/lib3.dylib] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1):

OK it took me a while to fix this error.  I knew that part of the issue was setting the *runpath* and the *install name* of the libraries, so they could be found during linking and at runtime, which would be the next issue you faced.

I settled for building the libraries into a common top-level `lib` directory, however at the end of the day I'm pretty sure that actually wasn't necessary, but it did cut down on command line options being passed to the linker which is very cumbersome as it needs to be done with `-Wl,-linker-option` and `-Wl,linker-option-argument` as you are using `cc` for linking rather than `ld` directly.

I think the actual answer is to add `-l1` to your `three/src/Makefile` line:

```
$(LD) -o $@ $< -l2 -l1
```

It's not clear to me why this was necessary as if `lib3` depends on `lib2` then it shouldn't be necessary to add `lib2`'s dependencies into the linker line.  It's perhaps something to do with your use of `-undefined dynamic_lookup`, as I've never seen that option used before.  However I didn't have time to experiment fully with this.

If you make this change to your version of the `Makefile`s you will likely have runtime issues as the *runpath* and *install name* are implied from whatever you passed to `-L` (which was `../../one/lib` and `../../two/lib` and they will almost certainly be wrong at runtime).  Therefore it's better to explicitly set the *runpath* and *install name*, and every library had their *runpath* set to `@loader_path/` and their *install name* set to `@rpath/libX.dylib`.  The executable that uses these libraries will likely want a different *runpath* in order to find the libraries.

See my [pull request](https://github.com/leedm777/bug-free-eureka/pull/1) for the changes I made.

I would like to commend you on how you presented this question with a testable project hosted on github; without that you would be unlikely to get any decent feedback.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer. I don't have the option of combining the lib directories in the real project, but the other info should be very helpful. FWIW, -undefined dynamic_lookup causes symbols undefined at link time to be resolved dynamically at run time. I wonder if that is cause of some of my problems...

Comment: @leedm777 I would try without.  In order to keep the libraries separate, it should just be a case of passing in more of the `-Wl,` options in `$(LD)` and no more.